# Two alien searching for a person from other planet who brought a weapon to eliminate those two aliens

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

- This movie was from between 2000-2005
- The story starts out with a woman from other planet who hid on Earth. She has very long life and she became the wife of many kings because of her longevity.
- She was followed by two aliens (who had destroyed her planet) hence why she had to run.
- She has a brother from whom she was separated when coming to Earth. She has her brother's hand and the two aliens give a synthetic hand to her brother.
- She has a holy ring which can kill these two alien and the end of the film has her inserting the (blue) holy ring into the alien guy's body.
- Because the body is possessed by the two aliens, this causes them to die.

Comment: This sounds like it had a very low budget? Also, how sure are you on the dates involved. Is that when you watched it or are you certain that's when it was released? Can you physically describe the characters? How did you know they were aliens?

Comment: what i remember, this movie was chinese movie, i remember the guy which became a main character is stephen chow or someone famous (im forgot), when the two alien arrived on earth, the first thing they do was possesing two police, 1 male and 1 female

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like the Hong Kong sci-fi film [The Wesley's Mysterious File](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wesley%27s_Mysterious_File) from 2002. From an [online review](http://www.notcomingsoon.com/WesleysMysteriousFile.htm):

> Wesley is an expert on extra-terrestrials from his association with the Aliens Analyzing Agency, an expensive, but secret, arm of the UN. **He meets Fong at an antique shop in San Francisco viewing a curio. It's a skeletal hand made from glowing blue crystal. Fong must have it because of its sentimental value. It was her brother's.**
>
> **Naturally, Wesley falls for Fong.** Fong is from Dark Blue. She is the sole surviving Blue Blood alien having fled her planet when it was infested by the Warlock Toxin Gang. **She and her brother, Tan, came to Earth 600 years ago after the lost Blue Blood Bible they need to battle the Warlock Toxin Gang.** The Warlock Toxin Gang appear to be worms with a hive mind forming a nasty gestalt; a gestalt that can change its appearance to match anyone it consumes.

Here's a subtitled trailer:

Comment: That is the movie!

Comment: I wondering this movie about 10 years... So, the guy is andy lau... This movie is the best alien movie from my point of view... Thank you for your help to found the movie name!